# QTreeWidgetItem not hashable in python3

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I need to port some python2 code to python3.
There I found that a `dict` of `QTreeWidgetItem` is created. In Python 2 this is working fine, as the object is hashable. But in python 3 you will get an error because `__hash__` is not implemented:

```
$ python2
>>> from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
>>> x = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem()
>>> foo = {x: 23}
>>> hash(x)
-9223363252877437056

$ python3
>>> from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
>>> x = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem()
>>> hash(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'QTreeWidgetItem'
```

I consider this is a bug or is there any reason for this, that I do not see?

The PyQt5 documentation does not mention anything in this direction, and for `QTreeWidgetItem`, there is only the C++ doc available, which does not help in this python specific case.

Comment: I find it a little surprising that `QTreeWidgetItem` is hashable, so maybe the bug is in the Python 2 version of PyQt5? According to the [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html#the-qhash-hashing-function), a type has to implement both `==` and `qHash` for it to be hashable, and I would expect PyQt to comply with those requirements for Qt types. Or at least require `==` for hashability. Anyway, I think you'll have to ask on the [pyqt mailing list](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt) if you want a proper answer on this.