# TreeEditor_demo.py Raises TypeError in Python 3

Tags: enthought, python-3.6

Under Python 3.6, [TreeEditor_demo.py](https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/blob/master/examples/demo/Standard_Editors/TreeEditor_demo.py) raises the following exception:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'QTreeWidgetItem'
```

when attempting to create a new Department or Employee.

A possibly related posting, for Qt5, is: [QTreeWidgetItem not hashable in python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140366/qtreewidgetitem-not-hashable-in-python3)

Is TreeEditor usable in Python 3?  If so, could someone provide a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the report. Provisionally filed by re-opening https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/issues/323

Comment: Thanks for responding Jonathan.  I was having doubts this was the proper forum for reporting Enthought traitsui issues.

Comment: For open source usage questions, this is a good place. Enthought customers are also welcome to use Enthought support. For bug reports like this (as on most open-source projects) the repo's issue tracker page is usually the most effective.